# how to post value from drop down to textbox

Tags: php

```
<script>
    function load(form)
    <?php   
    {
        $query = "SELECT roomNo, price FROM dbo.Room WHERE roomNo =  '".$_GET['roomNo']."'";
        $result = mssql_query($query) or die ("Error Query [".$query."]"); 
        $details = mssql_fetch_array($result);
        $price = $details["price"];
    }
    ?>
    </script>
    <table width= 100% border="0">

        <tr>
            <td>List Menu</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="opRoomNo" onchange="load(this.form)">
                <? while($objResult = mssql_fetch_array($objQuery))
                {
                ?>
                    <option value="<?=$objResult["roomNo"];?>"> <?=$objResult["roomNo"];?> </option>
                <?
                }
                ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtPrice" value="<? echo $price; ?>" ></td>
        </tr>
```

I can't get the value from the database on selecting the drop box.

Comment: Hello [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Where do you declare your $objResult variable?

Comment: Do you welcome an SQL injection explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

You run the query *when the page loads*.

You run `load` *when the select is changed*.

Since you want to use the data from the select in the load function, that won't work.

Submit the form to the server or add some Ajax.

Comment: I haven't suggested using anything else.